# Which is the more idiomatic method in ClojureScript for printing to the console?

Tags: console, clojurescript, idioms

I have two options for printing to the console in ClojureScript. Which is the more idiomatic?

```
(.log js/console "Hello World!")
```

or

```
(enable-console-print!)
(println "Hello world!")
```

My question is: **Which is the more idiomatic method in ClojureScript for printing to the console?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(enable-console-print!)` just sets `*print-fn*` to `console.log`. After calling `(enable-console-print!)` both `(println ...)` and `(.log js/console ...)` are functionally equivalent.

However use of `println` has 3 benefits:

- There is no explicit interop with JavaScript which makes code cleaner
- You have possibility to change logging functionality in one place - just set `*print-fn*` to something different (for example, use `alert` in browser, write logs to DB in Node.JS, etc)
- In case of [common](https://github.com/lynaghk/cljx) Clojure/ClojureScript code it's the only option (you cannot use `.log` function)